# restart a void in an activity android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, while-loop

I'm doing a quiz application with x questions. I tried to call the method in both while and for loop  to start a new question:

```
x=10

while(x>=0){
   // void to create question & check;
   x-- ;
}
```

and with for loop:

```
for (int x=10; x>0;x --){ 
 //void to to create question & check;

}
```

but x always return 0.

How can I create a new question in the quiz without restarting the whole activity ?

Comment: You need to supply more info if you want help, because the amount of code you showed has no problem. X shouldn't always return 0, so if it is, there's something else in your code that's causing it. Also, you need to explain clearer what you mean by restarting the question and why you're using a loop for whatever you want to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "x always return 0"?